# Parse can't find previous version? Rollback to previous version

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've been trying to rollback a previous version of my cloud code, however it seems to have disappeared.

Where are previous versions of parse cloud code stored?

Answer (score 0):

The previous versions are stored on Parse's servers, and you can rollback your Cloud Code using the `parse rollback` command.

So for instance to rollback to version 50, you can use:

```
parse rollback -r v50
```

For more information you can start with the [Readme here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cli).

Comment: I rolled back to a previous version, but then when I rolled forward, I couldn't find the future versions of the cloud code.

when I type 'parse releases' in terminal, the only version I see are:

v173
v174
v175
v192

What happened to v176 through 191? Did they disappear or get deleted?

thanks for your help.

Comment: @flote Unfortunately I don't know the answer to that. I might recommend editing it into your question for future readers though.